# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (Python)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, console, psycopg2

Function code, in which I got the error:

```
def create_poll(connection, title, owner, options):
    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(INSERT_POLL_RETURN_ID, (title, owner))
            #cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM polls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;")

            poll_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            option_values = [(option_text, poll_id) for option_text in options]

            execute_values(cursor, INSERT_OPTION, option_values)
            for option_value in option_values:
                cursor.execute(INSERT_OPTION, option_value)
```

SQL code:

```
INSERT_OPTION = "INSERT INTO options (option_text, poll_id) VALUES (%s, %s);"
```

Console logs, with an error and it's traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    menu()
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app.py", line 98, in menu
    MENU_OPTIONS[selection](connection)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app.py", line 30, in prompt_create_poll
    database.create_poll(connection, poll_title, poll_owner, options)
    execute_values(cursor, INSERT_OPTION, option_values)
    pre, post = _split_sql(sql)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extras.py", line 1317, in _split_sql
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: the query contains more than one '%s' placeholder
```

Comment: Per the docs [Execute_values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=execute_values#psycopg2.extras.execute_values): '... It must contain a single %s placeholder, which will be replaced by a VALUES list. ... " And there are examples to boot. Please in future make at least a cursory attempt at reading documentation.

Comment: changed, and got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app.py", line 103, in <module>
    menu() 
    MENU_OPTIONS[selection](connection)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\app.py", line 30, in prompt_create_poll
    database.create_poll(connection, poll_title, poll_owner, options)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+PostgreSQL_2.0\poll_app\database.py", line 88, in create_poll
    cursor.execute(INSERT_OPTION, option_value)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: That is a different error. You are using the same query `INSERT_OPTION` for different types of `execute`. First it is redundant and will cause duplicate key errors if there is a `PRIMARY KEY/UNIQUE index` in the values. Second `execute_values` and `execute` use different styles for parameter/arguments. See docs [Execute](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: I got this error after I made a single %s placeholder

Comment: Read my comment, read the docs at the links I sent. Bottom line is you cannot use the same query for both types of execute. Also doing both makes no sense.

Comment: Could you please tell me what exactly to read in the article what you sent to me, since it's a bit long: 
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: You don't have to read it all, look at the examples and the examples in the `execute_values` section and it will be apparent what the difference is. The primary difference is `execute_value` only ever has one `%s` whereas `execute` has as many as needed to match parameters.  In any case in your function you only need one style of execute not both.